# How to verify that html is stable (finished changing) in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver

I'm testing online Game here http://slotmachinescript.com/

I want to create a test to verify if credits value is the same after page refresh

```
public class VerifyGameAfterRefresh extends BaseTest{

@Test(invocationCount = 1)
public void testAfterRefresh(){
    GamePage gamePage = new GamePage(driver);
    gamePage.isLoaded();
    int times = getRandInt(2,5);
    //change bet value
    gamePage.clickSpinUpButton(times);
    //click on spin button
    gamePage.clickSpinButton(times);
    int creditsValue = gamePage.getCreditsValue();
    gamePage.pageRefresh();
    int creditsValueAfterRefresh = gamePage.getCreditsValue();

    Assert.assertEquals(creditsValue,creditsValueAfterRefresh,"Credit after refresh are not the same");
    Assert.assertTrue(gamePage.getBetValue() == 1, "Bet value was not set to default");
  }
}
```

Method to get creditsValue :

```
    public int getCreditsValue(){
    //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.
    int value = Integer.parseInt(creditsValue.getText());
    return value;
}
```

Everything works perfect until the case when after last click on spin user wins. In this case `<span id="credits">value</span>` value is changing dynamically, but my method does not wait till the end of the changing and grab the value at the beginning that after leads to test fail.

May I use some functionality of 
`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.`
just to wait for my value to be stable?

Or what would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to track whether page was refreshed or not, you could do smthn like `ExpectedConditions.refreshed` and `ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(WebElement)`. However the problem is, there is now way for webdriver to find out whether refresh already happened or it's going to happen in the future.
Best way to do it is to wait for smthn that actually changes to change, i.e. you're clicking button and see that state of button changes back and forth. Or maybe some other elements on page change? Also, be aware of the fact if page itself remains the same you may end up having `StaleReferenceException` in this case it'll be necessary to implement custom `ExpectedCondition`.

Alternatively you could try to do following things:

1. Wait for `document.ready` state
2. Wait for ajax state by checking `jQuery.active` state

Comment: Thank you for reply.
Tracking Ajax did not help me, so I just started tracking the button attribute condition